# Jquery UI Dialog Button confirm open URL

Tags: jquery, url, button, dialog, onclick

I cannot seem to figure this out. Once you click on the button, it should open a dialog to confirm if you want to continue to 'go onto this link' (i.e. google.com) or not. If yes, it should direct you to the link. However, I cannot find a way around it to work. I have two buttons with different links.

view jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uRGJD/78/)

HTML:

```
<button class="open" onclick="window.open('http://google.com')">Google</button>
<button class="open" onclick="window.open('http://yahoo.com')">Yahoo</button>

<div class="unique">Are you sure you want to continue?</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.open').on("click", function(e) {
        var link = this;

        e.preventDefault();

        $('.unique').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {
                    window.location = link.href;
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.unique {display: none;}
```

---

BUT if I use the following (http://jsfiddle.net/mJwMu/) - it works fine. However, I can only direct to one link. Which is not the case - I want to be able to direct to multiple links. (google.com/yahoo.com/msn.com/etc)

**HTML:**

```
<button class="open">Google</button>

<div class="unique">Are you sure you want to continue?</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.open').on("click", function(e) {
        var link = this;

        e.preventDefault();

        $('.unique').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {
                    window.open('http://google.com');
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

> .unique {display: none;}

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to use an href attribute (`window.location = link.href;`) where none exists (`<button class="open" onclick="window.open('http://google.com')">Google</button>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<button class="open" data-href="http://www.google.com">Google</button>
<button class="open" data-href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</button>
<div class="unique">Are you sure you want to continue?</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.open').on("click", function (e) {
        var link = this;

        e.preventDefault();

        $('.unique').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    window.open($(link).attr("data-href"));
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You are welcome, be sure to hit the check box next to the answer to let everyone know you've got a working answer.